# Typing dynamic object fields

Tags: typescript, unions

Let's say I have dynamic object which has a union type:

```
  foo: {[key in 'num' | 'str' | 'obj']: number | string | object};
```

Now i assign object properties as follow:

```
  foo.num = 1;
  foo.str = 'text';
  foo.obj = {};
```

And it works. However when I try to access:

```
  foo.num
```

And use this value f.e. to reduce it by summing up all `foo.num` properties - I can't because compiler tells me that `foo.num` is type of union. How to tell compiler that `foo.num` is type of `number`? I know there is a way with `as` but it is not elegant way. I've been looking for answer in `SO`, `Medium` and other programming sites but couldn't find solution.

Edit:

It was just an example. My real case is like this. I have an array of objects which I have to group by one of their property which is Enum type and then map them. So I am doing something like this:

```js
Object.values(Enum).forEach(
    enum => subjects[enum].next(
        array
            .filter(object => object.type === enum)
            .map(object => object.payload)
    )
);
```

I though best way would be create object which will store all of `subjects` but this make all `subjects` inside of this object of `union` type. If enum values change for some reason, I will need to change only enum type, nothing more.

Comment: Can you show us some example code from your real case? It's not clear what you're trying to do, especially with the use of `.next()`, which is used for generator functions.

Comment: Sure, give me a second.

Comment: It is  something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-rubin-zzmwv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark .

Comment: I still think you will need to manually map each key to each type, because there is no way TypeScript can type it correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have only 3 keys, doesn't it make sense to create an interface which explicitly declares the type of each key?

```
interface Foo {
    num: number;
    str: string;
    obj: object;
}

const foo: Foo = {
    num: 1,
    str: 'text',
    obj: {},
}

console.log(foo.num); // (property) Foo.num: number
console.log(foo.str); // (property) Foo.str: string
console.log(foo.obj); // (property) Foo.obj: object
```

See on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=22#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIgCuAtgFxFkBG0A3PoQM5hSUtSgDmDhy61AFaUBgiAjAMAvrlwJ0IFshiZKGLAF4cjAiQrIAjABodyDpQDkkAB5gLJvqMrYpJmXIVN0AGwgA6b3QuAAoVdD89AEoGeUUff0CQsL8OaI843wCg0Mw-UWigA).

---

Based on the code you've provided in the comments, you have an enum that is being used as a key. TypeScript will still need some manual help with assigning the correct type to the key:

```
enum NotificationType {
  FRIEND_REQUEST = "FRIEND_REQUEST",
  NEW_MESSAGE = "NEW_MESSAGE",
  GROUP_CREATED = "GROUP_CREATED",
  GROUP_DELETED = "GROUP_DELETED"
}

interface Group {
  name: string;
  users: object[];
}

interface FriendRequest {
  user: object;
}

interface Message {
  messageContent: string;
}

interface Foo {
    [NotificationType.FRIEND_REQUEST]: FriendRequest[],
    [NotificationType.NEW_MESSAGE]: Message[],
    [NotificationType.GROUP_CREATED]: Group[],
    [NotificationType.GROUP_DELETED]: Group[]
}

const foo: Foo = {
    [NotificationType.FRIEND_REQUEST]: [],
    [NotificationType.NEW_MESSAGE]: [],
    [NotificationType.GROUP_CREATED]: [],
    [NotificationType.GROUP_DELETED]: []
}

console.log(foo[NotificationType.FRIEND_REQUEST]); // FriendRequest[]
console.log(foo[NotificationType.NEW_MESSAGE]);    // Message[]
console.log(foo[NotificationType.GROUP_CREATED]);  // Group[]
console.log(foo[NotificationType.GROUP_DELETED]);  // Group[]
```

See example on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-lMOYD622mt1hvNuGT2XTg3JJVBFVLoer0fric57fhgt7o1pU0DoA).